# How to insert HTML symbols in an emblem.js template

Tags: emblem.js

I would like to insert a `&nbsp;` special character between two element.

e.g, after the `i` tag defined like this:

```
%i.icon-off
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments in the other answer, here are a few different ways I'd write this:

```
 i.icon-off
 |  #{t "menu.logout"}
```

Note the extra space before '#'. The one right after the '|' is optional and gets ignored if present so you have to use one more.

Could also write

```
 i.icon-off
 |  {{t "menu.logout"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way:

```
%i.icon-off
| &nbsp;
t "menu.logout"
```

But in other simpler cases, you can also use:

```
i.icon-off &nbsp;
```

Comment: You can one-line this and drop the % since "i" it's a known tag `i.icon-off &nbsp;`

Comment: In fact, in my case, the following element is a call to an helper, so I had to use this notation. Updated the answer accordingly...

Comment: You can still use the syntax suggested in my previous comment, followed by the `t "menu.logout"` line. I'd actually write this as

     i.icon-off
     |  #{t "menu.logout"}